# Capistrano: cannot start unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

I am having difficulties to (re)start Unicorn as I am deploying with Capistrano as well as manually.

This is `deploy.rb`:

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock "3.8.1"

set :application, "project"
set :repo_url, "git@bitbucket.org:username/project.git"
set :branch, "master"
set :tmp_dir, '/home/deployer/tmp'

set :deploy_to, "/home/deployer/apps/project"
set :keep_releases, 5


set(:executable_config_files, %w(
  unicorn_init.sh
))

# files which need to be symlinked to other parts of the
# filesystem. For example nginx virtualhosts, log rotation
# init scripts etc.
set(:symlinks, [
  {
    source: "nginx.conf",
    link: "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default"
  },
  {
    source: "unicorn_init.sh",
    link: "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{fetch(:application)}"
  },
  {
    source: "log_rotation",
   link: "/etc/logrotate.d/#{fetch(:application)}"
  },
  {
    source: "monit",
    link: "/etc/monit/conf.d/#{fetch(:application)}.conf"
  }
])


namespace :deploy do    
  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'unicorn:restart'

    end
  end
  after :publishing, :restart

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end  

  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:web) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
```

And during this process of deploying, here's the error that Capistrano gives me:

```
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deployer@IP: Exception while executing as deployer@IP: bundle exit status: 1
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: master failed to start, check stderr log for details
```

And here's the unicorn log:

```
    I, [2017-07-26T09:27:41.274475 #21301]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
    E, [2017-07-26T09:27:44.101407 #21301] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=/tmp/unicorn.project.sock (in use)
    E, [2017-07-26T09:27:44.101620 #21301] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (4 tries left)
    E, [2017-07-26T09:27:44.602753 #21301] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=/tmp/unicorn.project.sock (in use)
    E, [2017-07-26T09:27:44.603927 #21301] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (3 tries left)
    E, [2017-07-26T09:27:45.106551 #21301] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=/tmp/unicorn.project.sock (in use)
    E, [2017-07-26T09:27:45.107051 #21301] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (2 tries left)
    E, [2017-07-26T09:27:45.608434 #21301] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=/tmp/unicorn.project.sock (in use)
    E, [2017-07-26T09:27:45.608617 #21301] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (1 tries left)
    E, [2017-07-26T09:27:46.109480 #21301] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=/tmp/unicorn.project.sock (in use)
    E, [2017-07-26T09:27:46.109664 #21301] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (0 tries left)
    E, [2017-07-26T09:27:46.611021 #21301] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=/tmp/unicorn.project.sock (in use)
    bundler: failed to load command: unicorn (/home/deployer/apps/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/unicorn)
    Errno::EADDRINUSE: Address already in use - connect(2) for /tmp/unicorn.project.sock
      /home/deployer/apps/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/unicorn-5.2.0/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:122:in `initialize'

It says **    Errno::EADDRINUSE: Address already in use - connect(2) for /tmp/unicorn.project.sock** -- however, what does it mean exactly? How to fix it?

I tried to run Unicorn also manually from the server - `bundle exec unicorn -D -c config/unicorn/production.rb -E production`, but only got

> master failed to start, check stderr log for details

that's pointing out on the error message from the log above.
```

**EDIT:** Instances of Unicorn

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
rails     2134  0.0  0.5  13620  5640 ?        Ss   Jul24   0:00 /bin/bash /home/rails/rails_project/.unicorn.sh
rails     2347  0.0  1.6  91052 17136 ?        Sl   Jul24   0:04 unicorn master -c /etc/unicorn.conf -E production --debug
rails     2349  0.0  7.3 270292 74716 ?        Sl   Jul24   0:10 unicorn worker[0] -c /etc/unicorn.conf -E production --debug
rails     2352  0.0  7.5 270420 77188 ?        Sl   Jul24   0:09 unicorn worker[1] -c /etc/unicorn.conf -E production --debug
rails     2354  0.0  7.4 270628 75236 ?        Sl   Jul24   0:09 unicorn worker[2] -c /etc/unicorn.conf -E production --debug
rails     2358  0.0  7.6 270288 77312 ?        Sl   Jul24   0:10 unicorn worker[3] -c /etc/unicorn.conf -E production --debug
deployer  9330  0.0  7.9 269032 80364 ?        Sl   08:36   0:02 unicorn master -c /home/deployer/apps/project/current/config/unicorn/production.rb -E deployment -D
deployer  9334  0.0  7.2 269560 73800 ?        Sl   08:36   0:00 unicorn worker[0] -c /home/deployer/apps/project/current/config/unicorn/production.rb -E deployment -D
deployer  9337  0.0  7.2 269560 73800 ?        Sl   08:36   0:00 unicorn worker[1] -c /home/deployer/apps/project/current/config/unicorn/production.rb -E deployment -D
deployer  9340  0.0  7.2 269560 73748 ?        Sl   08:36   0:00 unicorn worker[2] -c /home/deployer/apps/project/current/config/unicorn/production.rb -E deployment -D
deployer 24279  0.0  0.1  12948  1080 pts/0    S+   11:13   0:00 grep --color=auto %CPU\|unicorn
```

Comment: By seeing your log file, it seem that you are binding Unicorn on socket connection. Can you check if any instances of unicorn is already running?

Comment: Hi @Sanjiv, please, see the updated OP. I have added there the output from `ps aux --sort=-pcpu | grep '%CPU\|unicorn'`.

Comment: So unicorn is already running and you again trying to start unicorn?. Then it is expected to fail as it is already running.

Comment: ok, I am going to manually kill them and will try to deploy it again